# Group Policy applied but Network Drive wont show up

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy, network-share, automount

Server 2012 DC + Server 2012 on the client side.

I have the following group policy in place:

[image]

The policy is applied when I run gpresult /r /scope computer:

[image]

Yet the drive does not show up.
Also the LOG file is not generated per the "Configure Drive Maps preference logging and tracing".

Where else can I look?

Comment: You may want to include the output of gpresult that shows the policies applied/filtered for the User (not the Computer).

Comment: It says it's "Filtering:  Denied (Security)".
I have set the WMI filter to just that specific computer I need. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Oh man...
I really should have seen that one coming...

Comment: Filtering: Denied (Security) - If the user account does not have permission to read/apply the GPO, that would be the cause.

Comment: @GregAskew
That was it all along!

You can post an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: But wait...that doesnt necessarily let me limit the GPO to just one computer. As far as I can see it means I must create a seperate OU just for this computer. am I right?

Comment: It's a User policy, so the security filtering should be applied to the User account(s)/group(s) in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had WMI limited this policy to just the Computer I wanted.

Once I changed the WMI to "Authenticated Users" everything worked great. I might as well add that ALL Computers in that OU were affected by this policy as a result.
So I took the Computer I wanted the policy to apply on and created an OU just for it. Then applied the policy and voila.

Credits to Greg who sent me in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

User account needs to have permission to read/apply the policy.

Comment: It looks like his policy has Loopback processing set to "merge"

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the policy is applied to the OU/Scope?
I assume the user had logged off and back in?

You might also want to run rsop.msc on the workstation to see what is applied